# Reverse proxy nginx to apache, https in php

Tags: nginx, https, apache2, mod-rpaf

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server) for configuring nginx as a reverse proxy for apache, everything works except for the last two sections.

1. From [section 8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server#step-8-%E2%80%94-installing-and-configuring-mod_rpaf) about configuring mod_rpaf, phpinfo should return `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '146.185.137.240'`, but I get `127.0.0.1`. How can I troubleshoot to see if mod_rpaf is working ? If I get it correctly mod_rpaf should rewrite some headers. I've correctly set the `146.185.137.240` address in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf` as `RPAF_proxyIPs` and restarted apache2 using `sudo systemctl reload apache2`. The address `146.185.137.240` comes from `ping robertvandeneynde.be`.
2. From [section 9](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server#step-9-%E2%80%94-setting-up-https-websites-(optional)) about https, I should have `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443` but I have `80`. Therefore, my php application (moodle.org) thinks it's under http and not https because `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is not set and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443` and therefore it's creating http and not https url everywhere, leading to a lot of weird bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the error, that's described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/393207/mod-rpaf-problems-with-nginx-front-apache-back-end-after-ubuntu-upgrade).

`RPAF_ProxyIPs` should be set to `127.0.0.1 10.0.0.0/24`, I don't understand what it means, but it works.